# Type in Gujarati usin g standard englich keyboard QT 4.8

Tags: qt, internationalization, keyboard, qt4

I am Using QT4.8 for my developement. Using UBUNTU 12.10 as a developement OS.

I want to type any indian language using standard keyboard on cross compiled Platform (ARM 9) using QT framework.

I want to type in gujarti,hindi or any local language using Standard English keyboard in using the QLineEdit or QTextEdit control.

I am using Standard unicode to present the gujarati characters.

I go through following link :

[Internatinalization in QT](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/internationalization.html)

I could not get any way how to do it.

What I should do ?

Comment: What does this have to do with Qt?

Comment: how we can do this is there any class that provides simple conversion ? I want localization of my application.

Comment: OK, so what is wrong about the link that you wrote about in your question? What have you tried from there what has not worked?

Comment: i am trying to use the Qlocale Class as well QTextCodec Class for my purpose but didn't work. is there any specific implementation. ?